# Are there any examples or documentation on using the Castalia source parser?

Tags: delphi, parsing

While I have written plenty of recursive parsers before, I have recently become interested in the Castalia Delphi Parser (why re-invent the wheel). I know this parser have been used in many projects over the years - but finding any documentation for it seems difficult.

Where exactly can I find the documentation? Or as an alternative, are there any clear cut examples on using it in a real-life parsing scenario?

The idea is to use Castalia for syntax verification of Delphi units, and (if possible) benefit in generating a node-tree of a program (with classes, their methods, parameters, result datatypes, if/then/else -- basically a full map of a unit or program). You could think of it as "half a script runtime" without actually running any code, just breaking it down into it's most fundamental aspects.

Comment: Please share your findings, what have you finally chosen/done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use JvInterpreterParser? it has only 2-3 unit dependencies... can be easily modified to fit your needs and you can also improve the speed, in a old test I've parsed a 80 MB file about in 6 Sec. on a Pentium 4 running @ 2.8 Ghz or so...

Comment: Then the question becomes: Are there any documentation/examples of using JvInterpreterParser?

Comment: @Craig Peterson yes there is a very good example, the JvInterpreter class, you basically start from the beginning and call something like GetNextToken until the token is tkEOF and the you know you've reached the end of the file, now the source of the JvInterpreter is pretty big, however for a basic usage you can easily understand how it can be used -- if you want more than that then you should start thinking and understanding in depth how it works and improve performance(if that's the case)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the Castalia Delphi Parser does, but TJvInterpreterParser is actually *not* a parser; it's a lexer or tokenizer. TJVInterpreterExpression and the various classes that descend from it are parsers.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler Jon L.A. needs something that will split a file or string containing code into tokens... as long as the parser, lexer, tokenzier, donkey or duck will get him to complete a step in the project the name is not so important...

Comment: Updated the description to better describe the purpose of my interest. It is for an object pascal analyzer. Which in turn is just one segment of the full program I'm designing. Every inch of a unit must be parsed and broken down into sections. Almost like a bytecode compiler would do - except without any actual compilation on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Using the parser is described here:
http://delphiblog.twodesk.com/using-the-castalia-delphi-parser

The post also references some projects that are using the parser.

Here is another one:
https://github.com/LaKraven/MonkeyMixer